# Is it appropriate to use blockquote for "made up" quotes?

Tags: html, citations

In a new project we have some "user stories" which are completely made up. Those users make different short statements about what they want/need.

Now first it was completely sensible for me to use a `blockquote` or `q` for the statements in my markup but as I was reading the html spec for these tags I asked myself more and more if it actually is appropriate to use them. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think W3C specs distinguish between fiction and non-fiction...

Comment: Read the third paragraph in the [HTMl5 specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element). It says, "... The source may be fictional, as when quoting characters in a novel or screenplay."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec doesn't say that [`q`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element) or [`blockquote`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) *have* to be things people actually said. In fact, one of the examples of `blockquote` is a Shakespeare sonnet.

So that's the objective answer: The spec doesn't seem to say one way or another. You could take the language *"...quoted from another source..."* really literally, but I don't think it's meant to be taken that literally.

*Subjectively*, FWIW, as long as you're not being misleading (regardless of the markup you use), I wouldn't call it inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the main reason I was asking myself is the `cite` attribute, which is of course optional, to reference the quote. Since you cannot reference made up quotes that kinda got me thinking.

Comment: Yeah, it was an interesting question.